# Why when I convert a string to a symbol using intern is the accesror function for structures returning an error?

Tags: common-lisp

I am by most standards a novice lisp programmer, however, I don't feel what I am trying to do is particularly complex and I do not understand why it is not working.

I am trying to create a database of events that occur throughout time and are connected based on how they appear in relation to one another. This concept is highly experimental and not what I'm looking for feedback on.

The idea is to generate a random name for the event (which are referred to as symbols in the program, bad style, I know), generate a random number of appearances for the event (which have a start time, a duration, and a period of time that elapses until the event occurs again). Then once I have created a random number of event types, and a random number of appearances for each, I'd like to organize them in a list in chronological order, but I am not getting very far because the name I am creating is generating a type error in sym-aprs-h, in the sym-appearances accessor function. It is trying to tell me that it is not of expected type sym, but when I run tests such as calling type-of on ran-sym-name it returns symbol. So I really have no idea what is going on.

```
(defun initialize ()
  (defvar *alphabet* '#(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z))
  (defvar *symbol-names* nil)
  (defvar *moment-chain* nil))

(defun ran-let ()
  (Coerce (aref *alphabet* (random 26)) 'character))

(defun ran-sym-name ()
  (intern (coerce (list (ran-let) (ran-let) (ran-let) (ran-let) (ran-let) (ran-let)) 'string)))

(defstruct sym 
  (name nil)         
  (appearances nil)
  (connections nil))

(defun ran-sym-gen ()
  (let ((x (ran-sym-name)))
    (cond ((member x *Symbol-names*) (ran-sym-gen))                 
      (t (push x *Symbol-names*)(make-sym :name x)(sym-aprs x)))))

(defun sym-aprs-h (s tm n)
 (let ((dr (+ 1 (random 7200))))                                     
  (cond ((=  n 0) nil)                      
     (t (push (list tm dr nil) (sym-appearances s)) (push (list tm dr s nil) *moment-chain*) (sym-aprs-h s (+ tm dr (random 14400)) (- n 1))))))

(defun sym-aprs (s)
  (sym-aprs-h s (get-universal-time) (+ 1 (random 101))))

(defun mchain-org ()
  (sort *moment-chain* #'< :key #'car))

(defun mchain-con (n)
  (cond ((= 0 n) nil)
        (t (ran-sym-gen) (mchain-con (- n 1)))))
```

As I said I'm new to the language and teaching myself by taking on a smidge more than I can handle. Any constructive criticism would be appreciated, however, I'm primarily interested in getting sym-appearances to not generate a type error.

Comment: With respect to `(defun ran-let ()
  (Coerce (aref *alphabet* (random 26)) 'character))`, why not just make \*alphabet\* a string, so that you can take characters from it?

Comment: **"but I am not getting very far because the name I am creating is generating a type error in sym-aprs-h, in the sym-appearances accessor function. It is trying to tell me that it is not of expected type sym, but when I run tests such as calling type-of on ran-sym-name it returns symbol. So I really have no idea what is going on."** What's the stacktrace look like?  Please show the error.

Answer (score 4):

```
(defun initialize ()
  (defvar *alphabet* '#(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z))
  (defvar *symbol-names* nil)
  (defvar *moment-chain* nil))
```

DEFVAR does not belong inside a DEFUN. DEFVAR is a toplevel macro.

```
(defun ran-let ()
  (Coerce (aref *alphabet* (random 26)) 'character))
```

Coerce over and over.

```
(defun ran-sym-name ()
  (intern (coerce (list (ran-let) (ran-let) (ran-let) (ran-let) (ran-let) (ran-let))
                  'string)))
```

Just pick characters from a string and append them.

```
(defstruct sym 
  (name nil)         
  (appearances nil)
  (connections nil))

(defun ran-sym-gen ()
  (let ((x (ran-sym-name)))
    (cond ((member x *Symbol-names*) (ran-sym-gen))                 
          (t (push x *Symbol-names*)
             (make-sym :name x)
             (sym-aprs x)))))
```

The result of `(make-sym :name x)` disappears in the Lisp nirvana. You pass the symbol to `sym-aprs` is that really what you want?

```
(defun sym-aprs-h (s tm n)
 (let ((dr (+ 1 (random 7200))))                                     
  (cond ((=  n 0) nil)                      
     (t (push (list tm dr nil) (sym-appearances s))
        (push (list tm dr s nil) *moment-chain*)
        (sym-aprs-h s (+ tm dr (random 14400)) (- n 1))))))

(defun sym-aprs (s)
  (sym-aprs-h s (get-universal-time) (+ 1 (random 101))))

(defun mchain-org ()
  (sort *moment-chain* #'< :key #'car))

(defun mchain-con (n)
  (cond ((= 0 n) nil)
        (t (ran-sym-gen) (mchain-con (- n 1)))))
```

Why not use DOTIMES or LOOP?

Style: you might want to check the types of `s` and other variables. It might also be useful to use speaking names and/or documentation.

If you look at the code in a week you won't be able to tell what it is supposed to do...

You also want to format the code differently. See my version.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to this, I have done a little restructuring. I am now only having one problem